Display Loses Signal After Splash Screen - Ubuntu 24.04
When I turn on my computer, I see the splash screen and after a few moments the monitor loses signal and turns off. In order for it to work, I have to unplug the HDMI cable from either the computer end or the monitor end, plug it back in, and then I'm able to see the login in screen. After that, everything works normal. This happens when I'm turning on the computer or restarting the computer. If I logout, I have no issues seeing the login screen.
My computer is an Intel Nuc and I'm running Ubuntu 24.04. I also tried this on another monitor and had the same issue where the display loses signal after the seeing the splash screen.

I have the exact same problem. Why was this downvoted? HDMI-detection on boot does not work reliably on 24.04. What I do: unplug monitor, boot, login, replug monitor. This works for me. Never had any HDMI issues since Ubuntu 16.04 on the exact same machine, this started with 24.04.

Same issue here, also with an Intel NUC. It started happening after I upgraded to 24.04.

Face the same problem. Initially I thought it because of windows (I reinstall the windows so). But after that I found that it Ubuntu Issue.  If u have Laptop, try to turn on without external monitor. It takes time to boot. Once you log in, the user connects the monitor. It works fine. I may work on the machine with kernel version 6.8 as my other machine works fine.

I  had the exact same issue, tried multiple solutions to no avail.
What solved it for me was updating to the latest kernel by following the below method:
Installing the latest kernel.
The title says that you want to install the latest kernel, you can use an automated script to install the latest kernel:
Install the shell script which automatically checks and install the latest kernel:
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pimlie/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh/master/ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh
sudo install ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh /usr/local/bin/

Run the shell script:
sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -c     

Install the latest stable kernel:
sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i

Press Y to accept the installation.
Reboot to boot into the latest kernel:
sudo reboot      


I have a NUC11 and am seeing the same "no signal" issue through HDMI.  I seem to be having better luck with a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI cable too, so maybe give that a shot.
However, it looks like it's caused by kernel 6.8.x as I'm seeing the same issue when trying to install and run proxmox.  The issue went away when I reinstalled Ubuntu 22.04 or installed kernel 6.9.x in 24.04.
I installed kernel 6.9.x using this method:
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cappelikan/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install -y mainline

Using the mainline app, I selected the latest version.  I also had to turn off secure boot in the BIOS to get it to run.
I'll probably go back to using an older version of Ubuntu until 24.04 includes 6.9.x+ by default.
